# How to use ZeroMQ in Xamarin for Windows, iOS and Android

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, zeromq

I want to use ZeroMQ from my cross-platform application that will target Windows, Android and iOS.

But none of the C# implementation that I found is PCL, so I cannot use them for this purpose.

Should I implement a P/Invoke solution to use it.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no PCL version, I'd throw the code of the .NET implementation into a shared library and include them in iOS, Android, and Windows. The libraries there aren't as limited as a PCL that targets these 3 platforms. If it doesn't compile, you could have a look at the problems and try to eliminate them by replacing them. That's why you should choose a full .NET implementation without a lot of dependencies (like https://github.com/zeromq/netmq).

Comment: Thanks, +1. is this approach easier than using P/invoke.